# How to request information from a router?

Tags: router, wireless-router

On a device connected to a router (ie - a PC), is it possible for that device to request information from that router?  Ideally, I would want to detect my router's make and model by making some kind of request to the router itself.  I'd want the PC to be able to make a GET request to it or something along those lines, and find out information about the type of router being used.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several technologies available:

- [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) (Simple Network Management Protocol): Most business routers support it, very few home routers do.
- [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) (Universal Plug-n-Play): Many home routers support it, very few business routers do.

Both these protocols have means to get a make/model of a router, but it's going to be more complex than just a HTTP GET request. You'll need to use specialized libraries to tools to get that info.

Comment: If SNMP is enabled, though, `snmpwalk -v 2c -c "public" $ROUTER_ADDR SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr` might work (where `public` is the default SNMP community name)